# Is there a way to run pytests using xdist by file(s)?

Tags: pytest, xdist, parallel-execution

I am trying to run 2 test files using xdist with 2 gateways `(-n=2)`. Each test file contains tests which are user permission specific. While running the test with pytest and pytest-xdist, I noticed some of the test fail randomly. It is happening because some of the tests from `file1` getting executed by a different `gw`. So, if `[gw0]` was running most of the tests from `file0`, sometimes, `[gw0]` also executes some tests from `file1` which causes the failure.

***I am trying to find out if there is a way I can force/ask `xdist` to execute a specific file or perhaps if there is a way to assign a file to a `gw`?***

`pytest test_*.py -n=2 -s -v`

also tried:

`pytest test_*.py -n=2 -s -v --dist=loadfile`

Comment: _perhaps if there is a way to assign a file to a gw?_ - that's what `--dist=loadfile` does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file for running parallel tests is correctly distributed (properly receiving `PYTEST_XDIST_WORKER` and `PYTEST_XDIST_WORKER_COUNT` environment variables), you only need to run:

```
pytest test_*.py --tx '2*popen' --dist=loadfile --dist=each
```

Comment: i don't have the variables, PYTEST_XDIST_WORKER and PYTEST_XDIST_WORKER_COUNT, I use a virtual env to run the tests. What should the path look like for the variables?